# Input Box functions not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

I'm a newbie here and in learning coding, so please bear with me...
I tried to make a code which gets text from an input box and writes it as an h1 heading. But the code just doesnt work. Please tell me whats wrong...

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtJob" value="software engineer">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">HERE</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var id=document.getElementById("txtJob").value;
document.write("<h1>"+id+"</h1>);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't close the ' " ' on </h1>

Comment: THANX A LOT IT WORKED!!! Thanks a lot everyone for answering!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
document.write("<h1>"+id+"</h1>);
```

missing `"`.

```
document.write("<h1>"+id+"</h1>"); //this will work
```

Answer (score 4):

Read your error console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (plus a line number)

You forgot the closing quote to your second string literal

```
document.write("<h1>"+id+"</h1>);
//                             ^
```

Comment: If it's unclear: Usually the error console is accessible by pressing F12 in your browser - gives you many other useful tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript below should work.  You forgot a double quote.

```
 window.document.write("<h1>"+window.document.getElementById("txtJob").value+"</h1>");
```

You want to use a good tool, download the firefox extension firebug. It'll show you the error in your code, and have a console output as well. It allows you to isolate the error as well. Also in Google Chrome there are a few extensions you can use, as well as by default.